# I have problem in the react state. It keeps on nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just a beginner in react and I think I am missing something here. Every time I fire a click event the state object keeps on nesting and I have no idea what's going on here.
This entire code is in App component.

````
  const [state, setstate] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    setstate(prev => {
      return {
        state: [...prev,data]
      }
    });
  },[])
  console.log(state)
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setstate(prev => {
      console.log(prev)
      return {
        state
      }
    })
  }
  return (
    <h1 onClick={handleClick}>Hello World</h1>
  )
}```

Every time I click on the header the state keeps in nesting (i don't know if that's the correct term.)

First time the output is: 
state: Array(1)
0: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1

After I click <h1> tag for the first time it becomes: 
state:
state: Array(1)
0: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, Title: "Rent", Price: 20000}
1: {id: 2, Title: "Food", Price: 20000}
2: {id: 3, Title: "Clothing", Price: 20000}
3: {id: 4, Title: "Misc", Price: 20000}
length: 4

As I keep on clicking, it keeps on nesting further and I don't know why it's happening. I want your help in this.

<Note: This is nothing. Stack overflow is just asking to add more details but I have already asked the question. So, I am writing this just a fulfill text quota only. Don't mind me.>
````

Comment: Why are you doing this ?     return { state } you should return state directly. And also useState doesn't support prev state, you can already access this state in this scope with "state" variable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: its beacuse you are returning `state` if you do `return { ...state }` it will work

Comment: Usage of <code>useState</code> hooks is not correct. Refer the documentation page https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach,

```
const [state, setstate] = useState([]); 
  useEffect(() => {
    setstate(prev => ([...prev, data])); // set array directly to state
  },[]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setstate(prev => [...state]); //based on your use case.
  }
  return (
    <h1 onClick={handleClick}>Hello World</h1>
  )
}`
```